# How can I automate the process of clicking on a hyperlink in an email, downloading the file, and printing it?

Tags: powershell, outlook

Currently I am regularly emailed (through outlook) a list of 20+ hyperlinks in the body of an email, which I open, save, and print one at a time. Right now I use 5 clicks for each hyperlink, which is very inefficient, but I do not know how to automate the process. How should I approach this?

Comment: Rather than thinking about the printing efficiency it might be interesting to consider a more "digital" workflow. Does everything really need to be printed? (I hate these "Think about the environment before printing" signatures in e-mails, but regularly printing more than 20 pages for an e-mail seems even worse?)

Comment: A more digital workflow would be preferable, however at this time i must print every page because that is mandated by the SOP

Comment: this is the kind of thing you likely otta use VBA for. the builtin automation in Outlook is fairly powerful. [*grin*] ///// if that is not doable, then one of the GUI automation utils like `AutoIT` or `AutoHotKey` seem likely. ///// last, you can use the Outlook COM object to control the app, but it is finicky and likely more work than using the builtin automation tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas:

1. Get the selected item using `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)`
2. Load `MailItem.HTMLBody` into `IHTMLDocument` object
3. Loop through all links in `IHTMLDocument`
4. Download each link using `XLMHTTP`
5. Save the data into a temp file
6. Create and use `WScript.Shell` object to launch the "`print`" verb on the file
7. Delete the temp file